# KeyError in group by query in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want group to paper_quality , paper_size and paper_brand fields which have common data and want to sum the balance sheets.

I have tried all steps which I know like using custom serializer.

```
class InwardDetails(models.Model):
paper_quality = models.ForeignKey(PaperType, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
paper_size = models.ForeignKey(PaperSize, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
paper_brand = models.ForeignKey(PaperBrand, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
thickness = models.CharField(max_length=100)
reams = models.IntegerField()
sheets = models.IntegerField()
job_card = models.CharField(max_length=100)
amount = models.IntegerField()
cost_per_sheet = models.IntegerField()
total_sheets = models.IntegerField()
balance_sheets = models.IntegerField(default=0)
account_access_key = models.ForeignKey(Ledger, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

serializer.py class

```
class InventoryListSerializers(ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = InwardDetails
    fields = ['paper_quality', 'paper_size', 'paper_brand', 'balance_sheets', 'thickness']
```

views.py

```
class GetListApiView(APIView):
def get(self, request):
    queryset = InwardDetails.objects.values('paper_quality',
                                            'paper_brand', 'paper_size').annotate(Sum('balance_sheets'))
    print(queryset)
    serializer = inward_inventory_serializers.InventoryListSerializers(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: If you get an error, you need to post it.

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome on stackoverflow! While without a error stack trace I can only guess what is the exact issue but I can see at least two issues between your queryset and the serializer.

First one - since you did not provide the `Sum` to your annotate as key word argument, it will be available as `balance_sheets__sum`, not as `balance_sheets`. Also, it won't be possible to set it to `balance_sheets`, as it would clash with the existing field - you should probably define this field on your serializer manually.

Second one - you limit the `.values` to not select the `thickness`, which is expected by your serializer - hence the possible KeyError. You'll probably need a dedicated Serializer for you aggregation, e.g.:

```
class InventoryListSerializers(ModelSerializer):
    balance_sum = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = InwardDetails
        fields = ['paper_quality', 'paper_size', 'paper_brand', 'balance_sum']
```

And then in your view:

```
class GetListApiView(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        queryset = InwardDetails.objects.values(
            'paper_quality','paper_brand', 'paper_size'
        ).annotate(balance_sum=Sum('balance_sheets'))
        print(queryset)
        serializer = inward_inventory_serializers.InventoryListSerializers(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: I am getting an attribute error something like unable to find pk

Comment: This is exact error - {AttributeError }'int' object has no attribute 'pk'

Comment: You'll need to post the whole stack trace of the error, it doesn't look like something that could be invoked from the code you already posted.